# Python- GET request from user input

Tags: python, api

I am trying to make a POST request in python3 without hardcoding, what I am trying is:

1. after running the program user will be prompted to provide informations.
2. these information will be passed to the 'payload' and 'header' block.

I wrote this code:

```
import requests
import json
import pprint

url='https://gorest.co.in/public/v1/users'
token = input("Enter your access token: ")
name = input ("Enter full name: ")
gender = input("Enter gender: ")
email = input("Enter email: ")
status: input("Enter status: ")

payload = json.dumps({
    'name': 'name',
    'gender': 'gender',
      'email': 'email',
      'status': 'status'
    }
)

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer token)'
}

response = requests.request('POST', url, data=payload, headers=headers)
pprint.pprint(response.json())
```

Bur receiving error:

```
{'data': {'message': 'Authentication failed'}, 'meta': None}
```

Comment: Did you set the bearer token right ?

Comment: Have you noticed that you are not referencing the values you got as input in your payload? you are using the string `'name'` instead of the variable `name`.

Comment: Note : do `requests.request('POST', url, json=payload, headers=headers)`, dont `json.dumps` and remove JSON headers, requests knows how to do it

Comment: Do `print(payload) `  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because here the error is

```py
payload = json.dumps({
    'name': 'name',
    'gender': 'gender',
      'email': 'email',
      'status': 'status'
    }
)
```

you are passing name = "name" as constant string by putting quotes variable name you can fix this by chancing above code as

```py
payload = json.dumps({
    'name': name,
    'gender': gender,
      'email': email,
      'status': status
    }
)
```

also change headers to:

```py
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': token
}
```

Comment: Thank you @kunal Sharma it worked :)

Comment: it's my pleasure ;)

Comment: if possible kindly click on the tick showing on my question so that i can earn reputations it costs you nothing just a simple click.